# File Put Contents New Line

Tags: php, html, mysql, file, web

```
file_put_contents('hfchat.txt', file_get_contents('wget.txt'), FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
```

This is my current code. I need to know how to put a line break, because currently it appends to the last line of hfchat.txt rather than going to the next line and appending.

```
file_put_contents('hfchat.txt',PHP_EOL, file_get_contents('wget.txt'), FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
```

does not work

Comment: Try      file_put_contents('hfchat.txt', file_get_contents('wget.txt').PHP_EOL, FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$get = "\n".file_get_contents('wget.txt');
file_put_contents('hfchat.txt', $get, FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
```

Answer (score 0):

To join two strings you put the `.` not `,`. So your code should be

```
file_put_contents('hfchat.txt', PHP_EOL . file_get_contents('wget.txt'), FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
```